# Passing variables through multiple functions python

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

So I'm trying to make a function that prompts the user for an option, and depending on which option it does something to the information.

Optionone() basically asks the user for information for a single contact, and every time this contact is filled out it creates a list in a list full of the diff contacts.

In optionthree() I am trying to ask a user for a contact they want to display. So once they type in the name of the contact, the code should display the entire list consisting of the contact's information (name, address, phone, email).

I've excluded the other options that are irrelevant to this problem.

```
contact = []

def optionone():

    contactinfo = []

    name = str(input("Name: "))
    address = str(input("Address: "))
    phone = str(input("Phone: "))
    email = str(input("Email: "))

    contactinfo.append(name)
    contactinfo.append(address)
    contactinfo.append(phone)
    contactinfo.append(email)

    contact.append(contactinfo) 
    contactinfo = []
```

This is the optionthree function.

```
def optionthree(contactinfo):

    search = input("Name of contact: ")
    if search in contactinfo:
        print("This is what I'm trying to figure out")
    else:
        print("There is no contact with that name in your address book.")

    return contactinfo
```

And the main menu function

```
def menu():

    option = int(input("""
        Menu Options:

        1. Add new contact
        2. Display address book
        3. Search for contact
        4. Modify contact
        5. Delete contact
        6. Exit 

        Choose an option: """))
    if option == 1:
        optionone()

    elif option == 3:
        info = optionthree(contactinfo)

main()
```

Right now, when I run this in terminal, it tells me that I'm referencing to the variable *contactinfo* before it is assigned. The whole concept of parameters and passing variables through functions is very confusing for me; what is wrong in this code?

Comment: can you make sure your code is properly indented? it is not clear where the functions end because of that

Comment: Return contactinfo from option1() and then pass the value to option3()

Answer (score 0):

you use contactinfo in the main function, but didn't define it in the main function. I notice you define a global variable "contact". Not sure if it is the same variable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to reference `contactinfo` before it gets assigned any values. If you need to have executed option 1 before executing option 3, then you may want option 3 to first check if `contactinfo` exists. If it doesn't exist, I would suggest writing that line as the following:

```
info = optionthree(optionone())
```

Comment: When I tried this, running option three just made it run the code of option one.

Comment: @Ji.Y I see now what you are trying to accomplish. You need to be careful about what variable names you use in what scopes. `contactinfo` is not used in the main, and is only used in the function `optionone`. Thus, when you call `optionthree(contactinfo)`, the interpreter doesn't know what you are referencing, because `contactinfo` hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here at Stack Overflow, we handle one problem at a time.  In this case, the immediate problem is the undefined variable.  Please handle the info look-up in a separate posting, if you still can't figure it out.

I'm going to get rid of extra information for illustration.  It's a good programming technique: take little steps.  First, we're going to get a name *only* into the list and be able to find it.  You have *almost* everything hooked up.

The basic principle to remember is that each function has its own "name space" (directory of variables and values).  Functions communicate with each other through the parameter list and return values.  Yes, there are global variables, too.  For now, don't use them.

The purpose of `option_one` is to add a name to the info list, and make the change available to the main program.  You forgot the last part: you have to send back the updated list when you're done:

```
def option_one(contact_list):

    name = str(input("Name: "))
    contact_list.append(name)
    print("OPT 1 contact_list", contact_list)    # trace what you do for debugging purposes.
    return contact_list

def menu():
    # Menu text omitted

    master_list = []

    if option == 1:
        master_list = option_one(master_list)
        print("MAIN ", master_list)

    elif option == 3:
        info = option_three(master_list)

menu()
```

Make your main program "own" the master list -- the option functions merely get a copy, do their "thing", and return the updated list (if needed).  The main program has to initialize that list, `master_list`, and hand it off to each chosen function.

Each function has its own little world: what it got from the calling program, the local variables it creates, and what it hands back when it's done.  Each routine can call that contact list by whatever *local* name it chooses; I've called it `contact_list` (as you did, but with "Pythonic" punctuation).

Output:

```
        Choose an option: 1
Name: Mark
OPT 1 contact_list ['Mark']
MAIN  ['Mark']
```